# How to implement network error alerts into my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, ios4

I am developing a view based app that requires a network connection. I want to add code so that my app gives an error when a network is not available.

I am clueless as to, whether or what code to put into the appdelegate(.h/.m) and/or viewcontroller(.h/.m)

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)?

Once you know you're offline you just might wanna show an UIAlertView.

You could integrate this code into the method application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: of your appDelegate.

I would not recommend to use such a feature as "test for network connectivity". The general problem with it is, that even though you might have connectivity when your app tests for it, it might be gone a little later. So I would just try to use connectivity when your app really needs to use the network and then handle error cases carefully and display meaningful messages and so on.